# Detemine if python script is called as subprocess and passing args

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script that gives the option to run a second script after completion. I am wondering if there is a good way for the second script to know if it was run on its own or as a subprocess.  If it was called as a subprocess, pass args into the second script.

The end of the first script is below:

```
dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Shall we format?",'Format Files',wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
result = dlg.ShowModal()

if result == wx.ID_YES:
    call("Threading.py", shell=True) 
else:
    pass
```

The second script is a standalone script that takes 3 files and formats them into one.  The args would just set file names in the second script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would retrieve the parent process pid with `os.getppid()` and pass then this to the subprocess as arguments using `Popen`:

*(parent.py)*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
output = Popen(['./child.py', str( os.getppid() )], stdout=PIPE)
print output.stdout.read()
```

and

*(child.py)*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

parent_pid = sys.argv[1]
my_pid = str(os.getppid())

print "Parent is %s child is %s " % ( parent_pid, my_pid )
```

So when you call the child from the parent

```
$ ./parent.py 
Parent is 72297 child is 72346
```

At this point is easy to make a comparison and check the pid.